# Extract points from a selected polygon in model builder [QGIS 3.30]

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, extract

My idea is to extract all points from within a selected polygon. I know this is a rather simple task if you use the tool [Extract by Location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location), however my colleagues have no experience in QGIS or any GIS whatsoever. This is the way I would normally do it:[image]

So I would like to create a model that automatically extracts all the points by just selecting a specific polygon. I do however, not find the option for "selected only" in the model builder. Do you have any idea on how to create such a tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved very simply by using the *Extract selected features* algorithm:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was it, somehow couldn't find that algorithm with the language set to German. Thanks!

Comment: @ibdmn: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)